# CalculiX installation error etime (In function `second_':)

Tags: makefile

I have been following the instructions to install CalculiX and its dependencies as best as I could from the wiki page https://github.com/precice/calculix-adapter/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-CalculiX
I have already installed all the dependencies.

In the installation when I say `make` I get the following error:

```
gfortran -fopenmp -Wall -O3 -o bin/ccx_preCICE bin/ccx_2.15.o bin/ccx_2.15.a /home/prasad/SPOOLES.2.2//spooles.a -L/usr/local/lib -lprecice -lstdc++ -L/home/prasad/yaml-cpp-yaml-cpp-0.6.2//build -lyaml-cpp  /home/prasad/ARPACK//libarpack_INTEL.a -lpthread -lm -lc
/home/prasad/ARPACK//libarpack_INTEL.a(second.o): In function `second_':
second.f:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `etime_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:101: recipe for target 'bin/ccx_preCICE' failed
make: *** [bin/ccx_preCICE] Error 1
```

I tried changing the line 24 in ARPACK/UTIL/second.f to `*      EXTERNAL           ETIME`, but I am still getting the same error.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Edit line 24 in `ARPACK/UTIL/second.f` 
Append * to get

```
*  EXTERNAL     ETIME
```

If you get this error when you are building the adapter for CalculiX, go to `ARPACK`

```
make lib
```

Go back to the calculiX-adapter-master directory or the directory from where you were building CalculiX and its adapter

```
make clean
make
```

For detailed guide please check preCICE [wiki](https://github.com/precice/calculix-adapter/wiki/Building-the-Adapter) for CalculiX adapter